# PHP strpos not working right

Tags: php, strpos

**EDIT:**

Ok for everyone who seems to be mentally disabled or something, check this out how it should be and why Halcyon's solution to swap haystack and needle DO MAKE SENSE:

```
$test = 'bla';
if(strpos($test, 'hauptkat') !== false OR strpos($test, 'kat') !== false)
{
    echo 'hauptkat or kat is inside $test';
}
else
{
    echo 'hauptkat or kat is NOT inside $test';
}
```

Comment: Where do you think is `bla`  in the strings: `hauptkat` or `kat` ? -> Nowhere

Comment: Wait according to the answer, you swapped your needle and haystack. **What on earth does `$test` have to do with anything then?** $test consists of 'bla'... Of course it wont match.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you've swapped your needle and haystack.

```
strpos("hauptkat", "kat") // 5
```

See: [strpos](http://php.net/strpos).

Comment: You are right i swapped that, it should be: if(strpos($test, 'hauptkat') !== false OR strpos($test, 'kat') !== false) ^^ thanks

Comment: @BungholeOK And that is why you should read the manual. But this still won't match `bla`, which is in `$test`

Comment: In his defense. PHP is notorious for swapping the order of the needle and haystack parameters.

Comment: That's right Halcyon, it's normally other way around

Comment: @BungholeOK for **string** functions such as `strpos` and `strstr` it's haystack then needle, for **array** functions such as `in_array` and `array_key_exists` it's needle then haystack.

Comment: @Halcyon *in his defense.* I dont know if you read his code completely, but this still makes no sense. Your 'solution' would still not get his code to echo hauptkat or kat is there.

Comment: @Loko I think it's safe to assume `"bla"` is a placeholder for a text that contains the needle. Technically you are correct but sometimes a little understanding and empathy is required.

Comment: @Halcyon Probably but OP is not clear enough. Also the comments of the OP that are deleted now, looked like he didn't want to explain to people who don't understand the situation and insults them instead.